# Is $\frac{s}{(s^2+1)(s^2+4)}$ not bibo stable? why not?

Tags: dynamical-systems

This is maybe easy for some people. But, I wanna know. Is

$$\frac{s}{(s^2+1)(s^2+4)}$$

not bibo stable? Why not?

Comment: Because $f(s)=\frac{s}{(s^2+1)(s^2+4)}$ has simple poles **on** the unit circle, at $\pm i$.

Comment: What is the definition of BIBO stability?